# Error in Cron with Directoy list - Magento 2.2.7

Tags: crontab

I moved Magento 2.2.7 from one host to another. I moved it myself. Everything worked except the cron. I installed cron using magento cron command.

Now every 15 min. cron is running and sending me a mail. Below is the mail subject and mail content. Is this correct or something is wrong with the cron.

**Email Subject:**

```
Cron <rbhomroh@cs-mum-1> /opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/rbhomroh/public_html/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/rbhomroh/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log* * * * * /opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/rbhomroh/public_html/update/cron.php >> /home/rbhomroh/public_html/var/log/update.cron.log* * * * * /opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/rbhomroh/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /home/rbhomroh/public_html/var/log/setup.cron.log#~ MAGENTO END 20c7f3f92a734843b2f4781ef0ebc235
```

**Email body content:**

```
grep: access-logs: Is a directory
grep: bin: Is a directory
grep: etc: Is a directory
grep: logs: Is a directory
grep: mail: Is a directory
grep: public_ftp: Is a directory
grep: public_html: Is a directory
grep: ssl: Is a directory
grep: tmp: Is a directory
grep: www: Is a directory
grep: access-logs: Is a directory
grep: bin: Is a directory
grep: etc: Is a directory
grep: logs: Is a directory
grep: mail: Is a directory
grep: public_ftp: Is a directory
grep: public_html: Is a directory
grep: ssl: Is a directory
grep: tmp: Is a directory
grep: www: Is a directory
grep: access-logs: Is a directory
grep: bin: Is a directory
grep: etc: Is a directory
grep: logs: Is a directory
grep: mail: Is a directory
grep: public_ftp: Is a directory
grep: public_html: Is a directory
grep: ssl: Is a directory
grep: tmp: Is a directory
grep: www: Is a directory
grep: access-logs: Is a directory
grep: bin: Is a directory
grep: etc: Is a directory
grep: logs: Is a directory
grep: mail: Is a directory
grep: public_ftp: Is a directory
grep: public_html: Is a directory
grep: ssl: Is a directory
grep: tmp: Is a directory
grep: www: Is a directory
grep: access-logs: Is a directory
grep: bin: Is a directory
grep: etc: Is a directory
grep: logs: Is a directory
grep: mail: Is a directory
grep: public_ftp: Is a directory
grep: public_html: Is a directory
grep: ssl: Is a directory
grep: tmp: Is a directory
grep: www: Is a directory
grep: access-logs: Is a directory
grep: bin: Is a directory
grep: etc: Is a directory
grep: logs: Is a directory
grep: mail: Is a directory
grep: public_ftp: Is a directory
grep: public_html: Is a directory
grep: ssl: Is a directory
grep: tmp: Is a directory
grep: www: Is a directory
grep: access-logs: Is a directory
grep: bin: Is a directory
grep: etc: Is a directory
grep: logs: Is a directory
grep: mail: Is a directory
grep: public_ftp: Is a directory
grep: public_html: Is a directory
grep: ssl: Is a directory
grep: tmp: Is a directory
grep: www: Is a directory
grep: access-logs: Is a directory
grep: bin: Is a directory
grep: etc: Is a directory
grep: logs: Is a directory
grep: mail: Is a directory
grep: public_ftp: Is a directory
grep: public_html: Is a directory
grep: ssl: Is a directory
grep: tmp: Is a directory
grep: www: Is a directory
grep: setup:cron:run: No such file or directory
grep: MAGENTO: No such file or directory
grep: END: No such file or directory
grep: 20c7f3f92a734843b2f4781ef0ebc235: No such file or directory
```

[image: When I installed the cron using ssh command, these were 3 different crons. but now all merged to single one.]

[image: Email Screen shot]
Please suggest if this is correct or some issue with the cron.

Regards,
Niraj

Answer (score 1):

As per image,  It need many correction:

1. Remove form last line: #~ MAGENTO END 20c7f3f92a734843b2f4781ef0ebc235
2. You need to setup three separate CRON Job for same time interval like:

   ```
   /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log

   /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log

   /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
   ```

   **Note** You need to change PHP path and Magento Root directory

Hope above will Help!

Comment: @Hello Pawan removed cron and reinstalled and edited as per the suggestion. Till now no error email.

Comment: following life is repeating - /bin/bash: /user/bin/php: No such file or directory - - in side magento.cron.log file

Comment: Did my solution worked ?

Comment: error emails not coming. but in magento cron file the following line is repeating - /bin/bash: /user/bin/php: No such file or directory

Comment: could you share screen shot for cron setup ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T4d4DTR5v41NdJ5bXXgQDsyitrGNeOS6/view

Comment: you php path is not correct

Comment: please check and confirm php path and replace with  `/usr/bin/php`. you can check it by `which php`.

Comment: its /user/local/bin/php. So i added local between user and bin. Hope this is correct.

Comment: New Error is --- /bin/bash: /user/local/bin/php: No such file or directory

Comment: got the error... in first line user is written, which is now changed to usr.

Comment: I told you issue is with `PHP` path.

Comment: new Error is -- mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

Comment: I think your server has not sufficient memory, please check Magento stack req.

Comment: yes, Memory issue with server. Checked with host. They claimed it is a shared cloud with 6cpu core and 6gb ram. But no memory for cron.