# Order - Sale related email not going in Magento 2.2.7

Tags: order-email

Recently I did following task on a Magento Store:

1. Upgrade from 2.2.6 to 2.2.7 - After upgrade, everything was working fine.
2. Chanaged server to higher configuration - shared hosting to shared hosting.

Order confirmation mails stopped after server move. To test I registered a dummy user and got the welcome email.

There was some cron related issue. which i discussed and implemented as per my other question. [Error in Cron with Directoy list - Magento 2.2.7](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266216/error-in-cron-with-directoy-list-magento-2-2-7)

Below is the current cron setting. When cron was created using Magento SSH command, cron run time was all (*). Now its changed to */15 - by it self - not changed by me.

I checked many previous answers but, most of the answers suggest some code change. I am a not technical person. Since emails were going out on previous host, I feel this is a some setting related issue.

Please guide.

Thanks,
Niraj